# Spring Boot JPA Select Specific columns result should JSON Format

Tags: spring-boot-jpa

Spring Boot JPA select Specific Columns result should in JSON Format

@Query(value = "SELECT id, property_id, display_name FROM property_basic_property_details WHERE status='1' and unique_id=:unique_id", nativeQuery = true)
public List propertydisplayname(String unique_id);

```
@GetMapping("/propertydisplayname/{unique_id}")
public List<PropertyBasicPropertyDetails> propertydisplayname(@PathVariable String unique_id){
    List<PropertyBasicPropertyDetails> PropertyBasicPropertyDetails1= propertyBasicPropertyDetailsRespository.propertydisplayname(unique_id);
    return PropertyBasicPropertyDetails1;
}
```

error:

could not execute query; SQL [SELECT id, property_id, display_name FROM property_basic_property_details WHERE status='1' and unique_id=?]

Output:

{
{
"id":1,
"property_id":pp_001,
"display_name":test1,
},
{
"id":2,
"property_id":pp_002,
"display_name":test2,
},
}

Answer (score 0):

In your Repository where you defined the query, mention List<Entity_Name> prior to mentioning the function.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id, property_id, display_name FROM property_basic_property_details WHERE status='1' and unique_id=:unique_id", nativeQuery = true)
public List<PropertyBasicPropertyDetails> propertydisplayname(String unique_id);
```

In the Controller, (the same way you defined without an object included, doesn't make any difference though)

```
@GetMapping("/propertydisplayname/{unique_id}")
public List<PropertyBasicPropertyDetails> propertydisplayname(@PathVariable String unique_id){
    return propertyBasicPropertyDetailsRespository.propertydisplayname(unique_id);
}
```